# Why angular directive *ngIF doesn't work with dynamic value?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, angular-ng-if, dynamic-variables

I have the component with some block inside which i want to show only on some page to do this i am using angular directive *ngIf,and subscribe to router changing where i get the current url. I don't get why it isn't working. Here is the code:

ts.file

Variable what i use showSignUpBlock

```
 public showSignUpBlock = false;

  constructor(
    private userService: UserService,
    private router: Router,
    private localeService: LocaleService,
    private soliticsService: SoliticsService,
    private pushWooshService: PushWooshService,
    private loaderService: LoaderService,
    private gtmService: GtmService,
    private routingService: RoutingService
  ) {
    this.subscribeToIsLoadingUpdates();
  }

  ngOnDestroy(): void {}


  setShowBasicLayout(url: string): void {
    const pagesWithSignUpBlock = ['education/academy/login'];
    this.showSignUpBlock = pagesWithSignUpBlock.includes(url);
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.routingService
      .subscribeToRouterEvents()
      .subscribe((event: RouterEvent) => {
        const currentPath = event.url.substring(1);
        this.setShowBasicLayout(currentPath);
        console.log(this.showSignUpBlock);
      });
  }
```

html.file

Block what i need to show or hide and ngIf whick isn't working is this one *ngIf="showSignUpBlock"

```
  <div class="login-form-signup" *ngIf="showSignUpBlock"> {{ 'login.sign-up' | translate:lang }}
    <span class="login-form-signup-link" (click)="navigateToRegistrationPage()">{{'login.click-here'| translate:lang}}!</span>
  </div>
```

I would be so thankful if someone will explain how to fix it.

Comment: You have multiple *NgIfs here.. Which one? Can you distill the question to just show the bit that doesn't work. Wood from trees ;-)

Comment: @JGFMK i specified the  *ngIf which doesn't work in description of question above and also specified it in the code by comment. The variable is showSignUpBlock.The block code is the third from end.

Comment: You have multiple spans, divs etc. Which one specifically in the HTML is giving the problem? One or all! If you trim out all the stuff that works you will be getting rid of a wall of text and have something more succinct to work with that will help others address your issue faster. Just a tip!

Comment: @VolodymyrHovorun did you try to debug it?

Comment: @alexander.sivak yes the value is changing after subcription but it doesn't have any affect to the block.

Comment: @JGFMK i just was thinking that with all fragment it will be better. Now i left only the one which is needed.

Comment: @VolodymyrHovorun when `showSignUpBlock` changes its value, then `AfterViewChecked` lifecycle hook triggers. Try to add this hook to your component and log values of `showSignUpBlock` there. If it indeed changes its value in the view, then you should see it.

Answer (score 0):

Try using [ChangeDetectorRef#detectChanges](https://angular.io/api/core/ChangeDetectorRef#detectChanges) after you set the showSignUpBlock variable. This causes angular to update the view.